# Answered bounty in comment, not answer

Tags: support

On [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/113388/alarm-silent-even-when-not-in-silent-mode) user [abhioxic](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/112588/abhioxic) came up with the solution in a comment, not in an answer. This comment was one hour before the bounty expiration, so had it been an answer I could accept it and award the bounty.

**Is there any way for [abhioxic](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/112588/abhioxic) to convert his comment into an answer and to accept the bounty?**

Comment: Well, Diamonds (aka Moderators) can move it into an answer, if they are satisfied that the comment indeed is an answer.

Comment: @Firelord: Thank you, I have flagged the question for moderator attention with an explanation.

Comment: Moderators actually cannot move comments into answers. They can move answers into comments only (/cc @Firelord). There's honestly not much that can be done in this kind of situation. You could potentially post the comment as an answer yourself after some time, mark it Community Wiki, and credit the original author, but the author would not receive the bounty in that scenario.

Comment: @eldarerathis Thank you very much for correcting me. I thought the otherwise was also possible, but now it's clear that it's not. (Although I kinda slightly remember  that it happened to me when I was a new user, but since you're a Moderator and know the stuff, I guess that memory is messed up.)

Comment: IMHO, abhioxic was correct to post that as a comment, since all of the points were asking for clarification. I think he was unsure too if it might solve the issue. Unfortunately, he didn't respond when you pinged him through the comment. Posting a community wiki answer crediting him is the proper thing that you could do (as you have done it)

Comment: @AndrewT.: Absolutely. It is just unfortunate that we didn't have enough time to turn his insightful comment into an answer.